# Emacs CUA Rectangle : How to prevent old rectangle from reappearing?

Tags: emacs

Sequence of commands

1. **C-return**
2. Move cursor to create rectangle
3. Decide that this rectangle isn't what I wanted to **C-return** again
4. Press **C-return** once more and original rectangle reappears.

This is unwanted behavior.  How can I turn it off?